# duplicated data when navigating without reloading page using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember.js 1.0.0-pre4, ember-data revision 11.

I have the following model:

```
App.DbProcess = DS.Model.extend({
    pid: DS.attr('number'),
    backendStart: DS.attr('string'),
    transactionStart: DS.attr('string'),
    queryStart: DS.attr('string'),
    stateChange: DS.attr('string'),
    waiting: DS.attr('boolean'),
    state: DS.attr('string'),
    query: DS.attr('string')
})
```

With the following route:

```
App.HomeDbProcessesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.DbProcess.find();
    }
})
```

I then have a template which uses `{{#each controller}}{{/each}}` to render all the processes retrieved. However if I navigate to other pages (without reloading the page) and returning back to the processes page, the processes will be retrieved again and the duplicates are rendered on page.

**EDIT**: I also tried this, but it didn't work:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.DbProcess', {
    primaryKey: 'pid'
})
```

Comment: what does your json look like? does it contain an `id` property?

Comment: I'm going to assume that you aren't returning a unique `ID`s in your JSON for the primary key, and so Ember is going to keep appended to the array. This is a requirement, or you can specify a different primary key with `primaryKey:` on the model. Ember determines unique records by the `ID`.

Comment: Edited, it didn't work.

Comment: The `primaryKey` is not working as intended, you will have to send the `id` field in your JSON until it is fixed.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I guess that's why ember-data is not 1.0 yet...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue now and here is my little hot-fix:

```
{{#if id}}
<div>
    {{title}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

In the template I render item from store only if it has id set (only those are coming from databse). But You propably solved it already!

(using revision 12)

Comment: Simple and effective :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can do something like this to customize the primary key globally

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
url: document.location.protocol+'//url-api.com',
serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: function(type) {
        // If the type is `BlogPost`, this will return
        // `blog_post_id`.
        var typeString = (''+type).split(".")[1].underscore();
        return typeString + "_id";
    }
})
})
```